# Changing permissions of Document Library items via Liferay Webservices

Tags: web-services, liferay, liferay-6

I've uploaded some files to the Document Library with the `Portlet_DL_DLFileEntryService` (`/tunnel-web/secure/axis/Portlet_DL_DLFileEntryService`). Now I'd like modify their permissions. If I'm right I could do that with the `Portal_PermissionService` (`/tunnel-web/secure/axis/Portal_PermissionService`). Could someone give me some working examples? Simple soapUI requests would be fine.

For example, I've a [`DLFileEntrySoap`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/model/DLFileEntrySoap.html) instance and want to add `VIEW` permission to the `Guest` role and `VIEW` and `UPDATE` permissions to the `Publisher` role. Which method of the `Portal_PermissionService` should I call and what are the values of the parameters of the method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Portal_ResourcePermissionService` instead of `Portal_PermissionService`, it has the following method:

`setIndividualResourcePermissions(long groupId, long companyId, String name, String primKey, long roleId, String[] actionIds)`

where:

- *groupId* equals with the community id
- *companyId* is probably 1
- *name* is `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry` or `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFolder`
- *primKey* can be obtained with `fileEntry.getPrimaryKey()` or `folder.getPrimaryKey()`
- *roleId* is the id of the role, you can obtain it through `Portal_RoleService`
- *actionIds* contains the permissions (e.g. `VIEW`, `DELETE`)

Comment: Just wondering, how do you go about implementing this answer? I'm new to Liferay and not a J2EE developer. I'm looking to simply have any file uploaded by any user in the Documents and Media portlet have it's GUEST role permissions set with VIEW by default. Right now each time a user uploads a file they need to go to the permissions page and check the view box so that other users can see/download the file - very annoying for the users. I was thinking of inserting a new row into ResoursePermission table and setting roleId=10162, ownerID=0, actionIds=1 however this is a hack, not good...

Comment: One of the best liferay answers I've seen, but could you still expand that what is the "community id"? Secondly; Is there a separate "DOWNLOAD" action for files or what action permission does downloading require? Thirdly; can I apply this to single users as well as groups if I just give userId instead of roleId to it?